# Does WordPress create a new Linux user when creating a new WordPress blog?

Tags: php, filesystem, linux

I wonder if WordPress creates a new Linux user when creating a new WordPress blog?

I am a NodeJS developer, but from what I know PHP scripts can also have access to entire file system. That's why I think that WordPress creates a new sytem user for every blog.

Is this true?

If not, how do they manage access between two WordPress blogs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux users have nothing to do with WordPress users. WordPress maintains its own user database, with its own permissions.

The linux user PHP is running as is determined by the server setup, usually whatever user that Apache/Nginx/etc are running as. If your PHP can access the **entire** file system then you have a serious security issue and should contact your sysadmin/hosting

Comment: I'm curious how are stored files (themes, plugins etc) of each blog. Why isn't it possible to access ones files from another php script?

Comment: Themes are stored in /wp-content/themes and plugins in wp-content/plugins. The latter part you'll have to ellaborate on what you mean, which PHP script and which files?

Comment: A theme contains PHP files. I believe they shouldn't have access to the other blogs, but how is this managed?

Comment: That statement makes no sense, PHP files are just PHP files, WordPress loads the theme, not the other way around. There is nothing auto-magical about a theme file. In a multisite install all frontend requests go through `index.php`, so asking that question is like asking how do you prevent a window on the 5th floor from opening a window on the 6th floor